# Command line to get SVN changed files only (exclude folders)

Tags: svn, command-line

How can we get the changed files and not folder in SVN command line?
I can use this command to get all changed files & folders:

```
svn st | findstr "^[ADMR]"
```

But I don't know how to filter the files only as I don't want to get the folders.

Thanks

Comment: You could write a script that pipes `svn st` to `svn cat`. The latter fails on directories, so you could filter the output of `svn stat` by the exit code of `svn cat` ... but that might be like using a sledgehammer instead of a screwdriver to turn a screw ...

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but...

In Unlx/Linux/MacOS X:

```
$ svn status | while read status file
do
[ -f "$file" ] && printf "%s\t\%s\n" "$status" "$file"
done
```

If you are in Kornshell, you can use `print "$status\t$file" instead of`printf`. If you are in BASH, you can simply use`echo`instead of`printf`, but only if you've turned on`shopt -s xpg_echo` first.